# compile error in xcode4 for libxml2.a

Tags: xcode4, libxml2

I just upgrade my xcode3.2.5 to the xcode4.0 .

But when I rebuild my previous project, errors happened below:

**Undefined symbols for architecture armv6:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      _xmlIconvWrapper in libxml2.a(encoding.o)
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      _xmlFindCharEncodingHandler in libxml2.a(encoding.o)
      _xmlCharEncCloseFunc in libxml2.a(encoding.o)
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      _xmlFindCharEncodingHandler in libxml2.a(encoding.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv6
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status**

Anyone help...

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether you still need the answer or not. Seems like you are missing linking with libiconv.dylib.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the libxml2.a static library may not have been built for your target architecture (armv6). Try rebuilding that, or...

It is possible to link against libxml2 *dynamically* (it is included in iOS). To do so, select the target > build phases > link binary with libraries > click add and select libxml2.dylib from the drop down menu.

Comment: I have add the libxml2.dylib to the application target. And also in the "Header search paths " add this "$SDK_DIR/usr/include/libxml2/"(full path:/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk/usr/include/libxml2/). But still the same error.

Comment: Did you remove the link to libxml2.a from the list? (perhaps I should have mentioned that)

Answer (score 0):

You should set Header path to

`$(PROJECT_DIR)/Your libiconv Dir/**include**`

(e.g, `$(PROJECT_DIR)/libiconv-1.14/include`).

And set Library path.

Then, check "Link Binary With Libraries".

If you do not set `libiconv.a` (or `libiconv.dylib`) to "Link Binary With Libraries" , set it.

Another method that you can check Target membership: project folder tree [see, Xcode left side] -> select `libiconv` libraries -> check Target Membership (check box on)[see, Xcode right side].